# can ElasticSearch only add field index ,no save the orignal value just like lucene Field.Store.NO

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, store

I have a big size field in MySQL and do not want to save the original value to ElasticSearch. Is there a method just like Lucene `Field.Store.NO`? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define the "[store](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html#mapping-store)" mapping accordingly, eg. :

```
PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "some_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": true,
        "store": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may also want to disable the `_source` field :

> [#disable-source-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#disable-source-field)
>   The _source field contains the original JSON document body that was passed at index time [...] Though very handy to have around, the source field does incur storage overhead within the index.

For this reason, it can be disabled as follows:

```
PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
   "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```